# Change Gnome panel icons to oversized faded style?

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-panel, debian

How do I change the icons that show in the panel for apps?  I've tried different themes, but perhaps I'm just missing a specific one?

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and my icons on the panel look like this terminal one:
(All screenshots are not my own, just found them for examples)

[image: Ubuntu]

I also installed Debian Gnome Jessie and the icons look like this Files one:

[image: Debian]

My question is, how can I get the Ubuntu icons to look like the Debian ones?  I much prefer the oversized faded style of Debian, but I would rather use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by accident.  After being frustrated with high cpu usage and overheating, I downgraded my Ubuntu Gnome installation from 16.04 to 14.04.  It seems the style that I wanted and preferred is the old style, and the new ones are the small regular icons.

I expected the style I was looking for to be a newer one since it seems more modern and looks much better, but I was wrong.

I am now using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Shell 3.10, with pretty icons, a cool CPU and an OS that suspends properly out of the box

Actual screenshot:

[image: Actual screenshot]